# How do I check if a window has focus in SDL2?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl2, c

Is there a replacement for `SDL_GetAppState` function in SDL2 from older SDL versions? Why was it removed? I want to use it so I can check if the user has focused the framebuffer window or not.

I found it in the documentation of the SDL 1.2.15 ([Documentation page](https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlgetappstate.html)) but it seems like it disappeared in SDL2.X.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`SDL_GetWindowFlags`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowFlags), it returns similar flags (among others) that you can use to check if the window has mouse/input focus.

The API has changed because SDL2 supports multiple windows.